# Why find's -exec option is including 'non-matched' items?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find

I'm trying to use find to find and exclude/filter few directories from being copied to another backup directory.
My attempts to do so using find's '-exec' option end up copying every processed file instead of only the matches, so I'm quite confused about what the expected behavior should be and would appreciate help gaining better understanding.

Starting point:

```
me@computer>ls
AddMonitorsOnEntry  MantisCoreFormatting  MantisGraph  PastePicture  XmlImportExport
```

Make sure find excludes the unwanted 'files' as expected

```
me@computer>find . -maxdepth 1 -not -regex '.*MantisCoreFormatting\|.*MantisGraph\|.*XmlImportExport'
.
./AddMonitorsOnEntry
./PastePicture
```

Now to copy those **2** directories to a backup dir:

```
me@computer>find . -maxdepth 1 -not -regex '.*MantisCoreFormatting\|.*MantisGraph\|.*XmlImportExport' -exec cp -dr '{}' ~/backup \;
```

Now to see if it worked...

```
me@computer>cd ~/backup
me@computer>ls
AddMonitorsOnEntry  backup  MantisCoreFormatting  MantisGraph  PastePicture  XmlImportExport
```

WTH??
I thought '-exec' only operated on the matches, according to this snippet from the man page: " ...The specified command is run once for each matched file..."

I know there are other ways to accomplish this task, but '-exec' seems to work well enough for the poster here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50612/how-to-combine-2-name-conditions-in-find/50633. I'm looking for help understanding **how to make use of "-exec" versus using xargs or something else**. Thanks.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now to copy those 2 directories to a backup dir

You don't have 2 matches. Your command shows 3:

1. `.`
2. `./AddMonitorsOnEntry`
3. `./PastePicture`

`.` is the current directory, so your `cp` command copies everything.

Instead of `find .` you can use `find *` to skip the current directory `.`, but still process all the (non-hidden) files/dirs within it.

Comment: Umm... 'tis late in the day haha. Thanks for clarifying, and for the tip!

Comment: Dropping the `-r` from `cp -dr` might help too, or adding `-type f` to the `find` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Silly of me..

My initial find expression includes the current directory as a result, so any files in the current dir will be operated on by "-exec".

To fix I added the current dir among the ones excluded.

```
me@computer>find . -maxdepth 1 -not -regex '.*MantisCoreFormatting\|.*MantisGraph\|.*XmlImportExport\|\.'
./AddMonitorsOnEntry
./PastePicture
```